# Webdriver access elements of a page which is embedded in div of parent page

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, automation, webdriver

We have a page(URL 2) which is embedded or loaded in Div element(Popup) of another page(master page) when a button is clicked on master page(URL 1).

I am not able to access the elements on this embedded page.

The firepath developer plugin shows, there are two objects (Top Window URL 1 and another with different URL 2). When I try to highlight any element with xpath locator on page 2 URL 2, its not successful as the object/document selected is Top Window. In order to access elements on page 2, the document needs to be changed.

Tried using SwitchTo method but no luck. The embedded page is niether loaded in a separate window nor in Iframe.

SwitchTo method can only be used if another window is opened or Iframe is present on page.

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions to change the document context so that all new commands are sent to this new page 2.

I am using C# bindings v2.53.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.ToList().Last());
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :( , the reason being underlying URL is different and hence its not giving access to the elements even when its the active window. The question is how to change the search context...

Comment: can u give me the web site to check

Comment: change the search context. ??? try to look if element exist in your code type string pageSource = driver.PageSource;

Comment: its hosted on local server.

Comment: what exception you get ?

Comment: Yes, the document object needs to be changed if elements are to be accessed on it. I Checked that element does not exist in the default document page source.

Comment: you tried driver.SwitchTo().Window("windowTitleName"); ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem and eventually answer to that.

Its really simple. Its simply working out with jquery.

{driver.executeScript("return $('body /deep/ <#yourSelector>')}

this piece of code simply draws the element from shadow DOM and which can be further used to simulate user actions... :)